# Is there a way to assign array to slice of an array in Java

Tags: java

In Python one can get a view of a list and assign a different list to it. Is it possible in Java?

For example, in Python I would do

```py
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a[2:4] = [1, 1]
```

Is it possible to do something similar with a Java array?

Comment: Not a duplicate: the other post is to retrieve an array, this is to assign values.

Comment: Can you please clarify to me (Java user), what is the expected result?

Comment: @YCF_L. That code sets elements 2 (inclusive) through 4 (exclusive) of `a`, in-place.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. In Java, as in C, arrays are pieces of contiguous memory. If you want to write to them, you have to explicitly set the elements you are interested in. This usually means writing a loop. Python of course does the same thing, but it hides the loop so you don't have to write it out every time.

That being said, Java does have a method for hiding the loop when you copy segments from one array into another: [`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-). So you can do something like

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] b = new int[] {1, 1};
System.arraycopy(b, 0, a, 2, 2);
```

A better approximation to the original might be

```
int[] a = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.arraycopy(new int[] {1, 1}, 0, a, 2, 2);
```

As an aside, the python notation `a[2:4] = [1, 1]` does not get a view and assign to it. It calls `__setitem__` with a `slice` object on `a`. There is a big difference, especially for objects like `list`s that don't have views.

Comment: shouldn't the python result be [1, 2, 1, 1, 5] ?

Comment: Why would it be? EDIT: what?

Comment: @YCF_L. Who ever said that it wasn't, and why is that relevant at all?

Comment: @agbinfo sorry I don't test the second one, in any way the first approach is not correct +1

Comment: @YCF_L. You are setting `a` but printing `b`. What did you expect? The python code modifies `a` in-place, as does my code. I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: @YCF_L Both approaches are correct. Your example takes part of the first example, then part of the second then prints the wrong array

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general solution to solve your issue of your problem :

```
public int[] setItemJavaCode(int[] a, int[] b, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
    int[] start = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, startIndex);
    int[] end = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, endIndex, a.length);
    return IntStream.concat(
            Arrays.stream(start), IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(b), Arrays.stream(end))
    ).toArray();
}
```

---

**Explanation**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]__> int[] a
a[2:4] = [1, 1]
  ^ ^    ^^^^^^______> int[] b
  | |
  | |________________> endIndex
  |__________________> startIndex
```

Comment: This does not do the assignment in-place within `a`, as the python code does. Also, don't you think it's a bit overkill to make temporary copies and streams for everything?

Comment: @Mad Physicist do you have another idea?

Comment: @Mad Physicist your solution is not complete it can fail in many cases, for that I create this generale solution, for your solution you can test with b = [1,2,3,4] and check what is the result

Comment: As with Python, you have to use sensible inputs in Java. My snippet does not seek to be generic, it seeks to answer OP's question.